Recreate a HTML element with JavaScript
a simple question: Based on the codes below, I would like to ask a question, is it possible for me to rewrite the elements using Javascript that were inside "person-infos" after having them removed by Javascript?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Testes</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="person-infos">
    <img class="photo">
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="age"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="testes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

const infos = document.querySelector(".person-infos")
const nomeCandidato = document.querySelector(".name")
const partidoCandidato = document.querySelector(".age")

const elementsInfo = infos.children

infos.remove()


Yes. Use document.createElement() to create them, and element.appendChild() to add them to the DOM.

You can also use document.body.insertAdjacentHTML() to add it as an HTML string.

These are all the usual ways to create dynamic HTML. Is there a particular problem you're having?

Since you have all the elements in elementsInfo, you can recreate the DIV, then loop through that list, appending them to the new div.

Why are you removing them from the DOM? Better to use a CSS class to .person-infos to hide them through display: none(or the property hidden), and then remove that class (or property) when you want to show them again.

When you remove div.person-infos, it and its children don't exist anymore. You have to cache the HTML of the elements to rewrite-html to be able to re-add them. Here is  a minimal reproducable example
doing that. Recreation of div.person-infos with the cached name/age element information is done using insertAdjacentHTML on the cached parentNode.


const cache = {};
const infos = document.querySelector(".person-infos");

setTimeout(() => {
  // cache the elements within div.person-infos
  // including its parent
  cache.elementsInfo = {
    parent: infos.parentNode, 
    name: infos.querySelector(`.name`).outerHTML,
    age: infos.querySelector(`.age`).outerHTML};

  console.log(infos, `removed`);
  // remove div.person-infos
  infos.remove();
  
  // wait two seconds, then re-add div.person-infos
  // with the cached information, using 
  // insertAdjacentHTML
  setTimeout( () => {
    cache.elementsInfo.parent.insertAdjacentHTML(
      `beforeend`, 
      `<div class="person-infos">
        ${cache.elementsInfo.name}
        ${cache.elementsInfo.age}
      </div>`);
      console.log(
        document.querySelector(`.person-infos`), 
        `with cached name/age re-added`);
  }, 2000);
}, 1000);
<h3>remove and re-add</h3>
<div class="person-infos">
  <img class="photo">
  <div class="name">NAME</div>
  <div class="age">AGE</div>
</div>



Or maybe you want to move the name/age elements from one element to another? Here's a way to do that (using insertAdjacentElement this time.)


const cache = {};
const infos = document.querySelector("[data-person-id='1']");

// cache the elements within div.person-infos
// including its parent (must be cloned, because
// after removing they won't exist anymore)
console.log(`cloning name/age from div[data-person-id='2'] to cache`);
cache.person1 = [
  infos.querySelector(`.name`).cloneNode(true),
  infos.querySelector(`.age`).cloneNode(true)
];

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(`children (name/age) person 1 removed`);

  // remove div[data-person-id='1'] *children*
  infos.querySelectorAll(`.name, .age`).forEach(el =>
    el.remove());

  // wait two seconds, then add the cached elements
  // to div[data-person-id='2']
  // using insertAdjacentElement
  setTimeout(() => {
    const moveToElem = document.querySelector(`[data-person-id='2']`);
    cache.person1.forEach(elem => 
      moveToElem.insertAdjacentElement(`beforeend`, elem));
    console.log(
      `moved cached name/age to div[data-person-id='2']`);
  }, 2000);
}, 1000);
.person-infos:before {
  content: 'person 'attr(data-person-id);
  display: block;
  color: green;
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
}
<h3>Move</h3>
<div class="person-infos" data-person-id="1">
  <div class="name">NAME person 1</div>
  <div class="age">AGE person 1</div>
</div>

<div class="person-infos" data-person-id="2">
</div>




Just as @Barmar said you can use createElement and appenChild to create and then append element into the DOM. If you want to add an element before others use prepend


const infos = document.querySelector(".person-infos")
const nomeCandidato = document.querySelector(".name")
const partidoCandidato = document.querySelector(".age")

const elementsInfo = infos.children

infos.remove()

let div = document.createElement('div')
div.className = "person-infos"
document.body.appendChild(div)
let img = document.createElement('img')
img.className = "photo"
div.appendChild(img)
let div2 = document.createElement('div')
div2.className = "name"
div.appendChild(div2)
let div3 = document.createElement('div')
div3.className = "age"
div.appendChild(div3)
let div4 = document.createElement('div')
div4.className = "IamBefore"
div.prepend(div4)
<div class="person-infos">
      <img class="photo">
      <div class="name"></div>
      <div class="age"></div>
  </div>




If you mean you want to recreate those elements using Javascript after having them removed. You can use the createElement property on the document object to achieve that. Then append the created element to the div with class 'person-infos'. A demonstration to that is.
const infos = document.querySelector(".person-infos");

// Create each child elements respectively
const image = document.createElement("img")
image.classList.add("photo");
const name = document.createElement("div");
name.classList.add("name");
const age = document.createElement("div");
age.classList.add("age");

// Append those nodes to their parent element
infos.appendChild("image");
infos.appendChild("name");
infos.appendChild("age");

I hope this answers your question.

I'm actually curious here because I think your question can be interpreted two ways:

You're trying to just re-create the element from scratch, or:

You want to just remove the element(s) from the dom to be restored at a later time, maybe you don't have a good way to remember the data attached to it or it was dynamic and you don't know what the contents were.


In both cases, yes, they're both possible and the solution is basically the same.
Here's examples that are easier than completely re-creating the element(s) you want to remove and then add back later:
index.html:
<div class='parent-element'>
    <p class='child-element'>This is static text that is always the same.</p>
</div>

script.js (vanilla solution):
// Remove the element
const parent_element = document.querySelector('.parent-element);
const child_element = document.querySelector('.child-element);
parent_element.remove(child_element);

// Put it back (there's a couple different ways but here's one of them):
parent_element.appendChild(child_element);

script.js (JQuery solution):
// Fetch the parent element & remove the child element
const parent_element $('.parent-element');
const child_element = $('.child-element').detach(); // detach maintains event handlers/etc, don't use .remove() here!!!

// Put the child element back
parent_element.append(child_element);

Keep in mind that both of these examples should maintain all the data associated with the child-element (the element we removed and later put back on the DOM)
